# Chain rule when sum is differentiable but individual functions are not

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Let $g_1 , g_2 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Suppose we know that the following derivative exists at some point $x_0$:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[g_1(f_1(x))+g_2(f_2(x))]
$$
but do not know if $f_1$ and $f_2$ individually are differentiable at that point.

Can we write the above derivative at that point as follows?
$$
\frac{d}{dx}|_{x=x_0}[g_1'(f_1(x_0))\cdot f_1(x) + g_2'(f_2(x_0))\cdot f_2(x)]
$$

Comment: No, the differentiability of $f_1,f_2$ has essentially nothing to do with that of $g_1\circ f_1+g_2\circ f_2$

Comment: I think OP perhaps means to take inner derivatives at $f_1(x_0)$ and $f_2(x_0)$, and outer derivative at $x_0$, for some fixed $x_0$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct---sorry for the confusion. The inner derivatives are taken at $f_1(x_0)$, $f_2(x_0)$; the outer derivative is taken at $x_0$.

Comment: I would appreciate a suggestion on how to write it to make this clear.

Comment: I've edited the question; hope this clarifies what I had in mind.

Comment: I think you want   $$\frac{d}{dx}|_{x=x_0}(g_1'(f_1(x_0))\cdot f_1(x) + g_2'(f_2(x_0)) \cdot f_2(x))$$

Comment: That's right! Thank you, let me edit

Comment: It would be more clear if you instead wrote the definition of the derivative, please see my edit

Comment: I think it is unfair to change your question after receiving a valid answer. Better edit a new post, with a link to this one making explicit this is a follow up.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of that norm! Let me do that.

Comment: Done: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782745/derivative-of-sum-of-compositions. I acknowledged the correct answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We alas cannot write the derivative this way. [Updated with more parseable counterexample].

As a counterexample, let $f_1(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$, $g_1(x)=x^3$, and let $f_2\equiv g_2\equiv 0$.

Then let $h(x)=g_1(f_1(x)) + g_2(f_2(x)) = x$,
so $h'(0)=1$, yet
$$g_1'(f_1(0))\cdot f_1(x)+g_2'(f_2(0))\cdot f_2(x)\equiv 0,$$ and so we have
$$\frac{d}{dx}|_{x=0}(g_1'(f_1(0))\cdot f_1(x)+g_2'(f_2(0))\cdot f_2(x))=0.$$

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: As a follow up: might we be able to write it this way if we also knew that $g_1,g_2$ were twice-differentiable, and their derivatives were strictly positive everywhere? Your counterexample relies on $g_1'(0)=0$.

Comment: Btw, I acknowledged your answer and posted the follow up as a separate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782745/derivative-of-sum-of-compositions. Thanks again!