# Derivative of sum of compositions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

**A follow up to a previous question:** [Chain rule when sum is differentiable but individual functions are not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782327/chain-rule-when-sum-is-differentiable-but-individual-functions-are-not?fbclid=IwAR3CLPaKWK6qositm5l_iHZt7k7fYZkee1hTr4Ue3qRhsuLEGJOrp0p2Ii8#4782341)

Take some $g_1, g_2, h_1,h_2: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ that are everywhere twice differentiable and and always have a strictly positive derivative. Take also some $f_1,f_2: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which need not be differentiable. However, we know that for some $x_0$:
$$
g_1'(f_1(x_0)) = h_1'(f_1(x_0)) >0
$$
$$
g_2'(f_2(x_0)) = h_2'(f_2(x_0)) >0
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[g_1(f_1(x))+ g_2(f_2(x))] \big|_{x=x_0} = 0
$$
(We only know that the above derivative exists at $x_0$, not everywhere). Can we say the following?
$$
        \frac{d}{dx}[h_1(f_1(x))+ h_2(f_2(x))] \big|_{x=x_0} = 0
$$
(We do not assume that the derivative right above exists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$f_1(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$, $f_2(x)=-x^{\frac{1}{3}}$, let $g_1(x)=g_2(x)=x$, and let $h_1(x)=x+x^3$, $h_2(x)=x$.

Then certainly $g_1$, $g_2$, $h_1$, $h_2$ are twice differentiable with strictly positive derivatives which coincide at $f_1(0)=f_2(0)=0$.

Moreover, we have $$g_1(f_1(x))+g_2(f_2(x))= x^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{3}}=0$$ everywhere, so certainly the conditions of the question are satisfied.

However,
$$h_1(f_1(x))+h_2(f_2(x)) = x^{\frac{1}{3}}+ x + (-x^\frac{1}{3})=x,$$ so
$$\frac{d}{dx}[h_1(f_1(x))+ h_2(f_2(x))] \big|_{x=0} = 1.$$

Comment: @M W, Great, thank you!